# python selenium locate ajax pop up window element

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, selenium, css-selectors

Having a hard time trying to locate an element a pop up window .Tried switching frames and windows to no avail . Element not found in original source code. len(driver.window_handles) also = 1 after pop up. Here is what I tried when the pop up is active.

```
windows = driver.window_handles
num_of_windows = len(windows)
print (num_of_windows)
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open').click()
```

Here is the html that shows in Firebug

```
 <button class="suv suv-deca suv-open" type="button">Click Here to Continue</button>
```

Comment: What kind of pop-up it is? How do you want to handle it? If it is an application-native pop-up, show its `HTML` code

Comment: The code is in HTML which Im trying to get driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open') after verifying with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If result of `len(driver.window_handles)` is `1`, as you've mentioned, then `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])`, obviously should raise `http.client.CannotSendRequest` exception as there is only one window available. Try just

```
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open').click()
```

without switching to windows, alerts, etc

Comment: Thanks, However thats where I started off before I noticed I was dealing with a pop up.

Comment: Your button could be embedded in `iframe`. Check if there is any `iframe` ancestor

Comment: I checked the source code , there is an Iframe on the page but the button isnt embedded in it.

Comment: From what I gather it looks like a Modal Dialog.

Comment: And what do you mean `Element not found in original source code`?

Comment: Hmm What I mean by that is when I have a look at the source of the main page before the pop up , the element cant be located. However after the pop ups been initiated can I locate it via firebug.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions after `click()`?

Comment: I get an ElementNotVisibleException before the wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.suv.suv-deca.suv-open').click() hence cant click